# Snowflake - UDF compilation error if query using UDF returns no data

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA
(
  READING    NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE TABLE TEST_VALIDATE
(
  MNEMONIC          VARCHAR2(3),
  MINIMUM_VALUE     NUMBER(3),
  MAXIMUM_VALUE     NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST_RANGE( p_mnemonic VARCHAR2, p_reading NUMBER )
RETURNS NUMBER AS
'SELECT
MAX(CASE
    WHEN p_reading BETWEEN MINIMUM_VALUE AND MAXIMUM_VALUE THEN p_reading
    WHEN p_reading < MINIMUM_VALUE THEN MINIMUM_VALUE
    WHEN p_reading > MAXIMUM_VALUE THEN MAXIMUM_VALUE
    ELSE NULL
END)
FROM TEST_VALIDATE
WHERE MNEMONIC = p_mnemonic';
```

All rows in table TEST_DATA is validated against TEST_VALIDATE (via a UDF) so that the values are adjusted to a range.  Run these below to see something I don't understand:

```
-- If there is no data in both tables, this runs fine, returning nothing:
SELECT
    TEST_RANGE( 'XX', READING )
FROM TEST_DATA;

-- Insert a row to TEST_VALIDATE
INSERT INTO TEST_VALIDATE ( MNEMONIC, MINIMUM_VALUE, MAXIMUM_VALUE ) VALUES ( 'XX', 2, 100 );

-- Now this same query aborts with "002031 (42601): SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"
SELECT
    TEST_RANGE( 'XX', READING )
FROM TEST_DATA;

-- Add a row to the data table:
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA ( READING ) VALUES ( 111 );

-- Now this query runs again returning one row:
SELECT
    TEST_RANGE( 'XX', READING )
FROM TEST_DATA;

-- This also works returning no rows:
SELECT
    TEST_RANGE( 'OO', READING )
FROM TEST_DATA;
```

What could be happening?

Comment: Just to add that you can simplify the above test to:<br/>
`code
SELECT
    READING,
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN READING BETWEEN MINIMUM_VALUE AND MAXIMUM_VALUE THEN READING
            END
        FROM EDW_WEATHER.TEST_VALIDATE
        WHERE MNEMONIC = 'AT'
    )
FROM TEST_DATA;`<br/>
If table TEST_DATA has only one record, this is successful.  If there are more data, this fails to compile!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is snowflake, "your corolated sub-query is too tricky for me" message. This form seems to be related to the [Scalar Subquery](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html#scalar-subqueries). MAX by itself is in effect a GROUP BY, which might be why the trigger is happening..

When snowflake metadata knows what's in tables, it knows how to write the query to work. It might also start to fail if you put lots of data into the `test_data` table, with this message.

But when the tables are empty, it doesn't know what is in the table, so doesn't know how to write an optimized query. *Which might imply skip empty tables*

anyways your SQL is in effect this:

```
WITH test_validate(mnemonic, minimum_value, maximum_value) AS (
  SELECT 'XX', 2, 100
), test_data(reading) AS (
  SELECT * FROM values (111)
)
SELECT
   (SELECT
        MAX(
          CASE
                WHEN td.reading BETWEEN tv.minimum_value AND tv.maximum_value THEN td.reading
                WHEN td.reading < tv.minimum_value THEN tv.minimum_value
                WHEN td.reading > tv.maximum_value THEN tv.maximum_value
                ELSE NULL
            END)
    FROM test_validate AS tv
    WHERE tv.mnemonic = 'XX')
FROM test_data AS td
```

this can be rewritten as:

```
WITH test_validate(mnemonic, minimum_value, maximum_value) AS (
  SELECT 'XX', 2, 100
), test_data(reading) AS (
  SELECT 1 limit 0
  --SELECT 111
)
SELECT
    MAX(
        CASE
              WHEN td.reading BETWEEN tv.minimum_value AND tv.maximum_value THEN td.reading
              WHEN td.reading < tv.minimum_value THEN tv.minimum_value
              WHEN td.reading > tv.maximum_value THEN tv.maximum_value
              ELSE NULL
          END
     )
FROM test_data AS td
CROSS JOIN test_validate AS tv
WHERE tv.mnemonic = 'XX'
```

which gives a single value of NULL, because there are no rows in `test_data` and then across those rows MAX is run (as GROUPING function) and given there is no input, it returns NULL.

Comment: The MAX() in the UDF is redundant in this situation.  If is to ensure that only one row is returned and was added to address another situation.  However, even if you remove that MAX(), it still returns an error on execution

Comment: The rewrite SQL is still happy with or without the MAX. That is my key point, sub-selects are a tricky edge case to program for, thus the "this doesn't work don't do it" error message. I would strongly encourage not hiding logic in functions. Which is the normal reason for use functions like this. OR open a support ticket, and get them to cover your use case.

Comment: @SnowFlow also interested to discus the original problem trying to be solved, because there might be cleaner paths to the desired outcome that avoid problems. But on thinking more, this really does seem like a bug, I would open a support case.